# How do I specify optional flags?

Tags: c, printing, flags

I have to specify these flags/arguments. If an argument is missing, use the specified default values for the flag. If an argument cannot be converted into a numeric value, then use the default value for that argument.

-eye: If this flag is present, then the next three arguments specify the x, y, and z coordinates of the position of the eye. If this flag is not present, then the eye defaults to position <0.0, 0.0, -14.0>.

-view: If this flag is present, then the next six arguments specify the min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, width, and height components of the view rectangle. If the flag is not present, then the view rectangle defaults to position min_x of -10, max_x of 10, min_y of -7.5, max_y of 7.5, width of 1024, and height of 768.

-light: If this flag is present, then the next six arguments specify the x, y, and z coordinates of the light's position and the r, g, and b values of the light's color. If the flag is not present, then the light defaults to position <-100.0, 100.0, -100.0> and color/intensity (1.5, 1.5, 1.5).

-ambient: If this flag is present, then the next three arguments specify the r, g, and b values of the ambient light color. If the flag is not present, then the ambient light color defaults to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

I'm thinking, do I have to create a function for each of these flags? I'm a bit confused on how I would incorporate this into my code so far:

```
#include "commandline.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   FILE *input;

   input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if (input == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Usually something like: "Filename required. Usage: a.out <filename> [-eye ..."

Comment: So, is that what I would put in the "else" statement?

Comment: @Karen no this if() should be first statements  in your main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
if(argc < NoOfArgumentNeeded){
 fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s message string", argv[0]);
 return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

You can write separate `Usage()`, here are some good examples: (1) [A Little C Primer/C Command Line Arguments](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Command_Line_Arguments), (2) [Command Line Parameter Parsing](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-command-line-parameter-parsing)

**Edit**:

Stderr is useful when you wants to print error message

[Stderr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stderr/):

> **Standard error stream:** The standard error stream is the default destination for error messages and other diagnostic warnings. Like
>   stdout, it is usually also directed by default to the text console
>   (generally, on the screen).
>
> stderr can be used as an argument for any function that takes an
>   argument of type FILE* expecting an output stream, like fputs or
>   fprintf.

Comment: I think so, but could I say" fprintf("usage: a.out......")? Or is that not how I would print a usage message?

Comment: `printf` prints on stdin by default, using `fprintf()` I am printing error message on `stderr` that is standard error device

Comment: @Karen, You can use printf to print usage message. as Grijesh mentioned its good practice to follow what he just said.

Comment: @Karen if your help/message is long then you can write a separate `usage()` and call it from main.